# Delete row button deleting other row instead

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a couple of macros, one that creates a shape in a determined row with a macro assigned and the macro assigned that deletes the row when the shape is clicked on. The macro that adds the shape is activated by another macro that populates the last empty row of my table with relevant data and the shape to delete the row in question, but I'll leave that one out of it.

So the macros should add the shape to the row being populated and, once the shape gets clicked, it gets the shape's row and delete it.

Here are the macros:

--The one that creates the shape:

```
Sub addDelBt(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rw As Long
rw = Target.Row
Dim shp As Object
Set shp = Plan1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeMathMultiply, Target.Left + 2.5, Target.Top + 2.5, Target.RowHeight - 2, Target.RowHeight - 2)
    'shp.Width = 11
    'shp.Height = 11
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(170, 170, 170)
    shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    With shp.Shadow
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 128)
        .OffsetX = 0.5
        .OffsetY = 2
        .Transparency = 0.5
        .Visible = True
    End With
    With shp.ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelCircle
        .BevelTopInset = 15
        .BevelTopDepth = 3
        .PresetLighting = msoLightRigBalanced
        .LightAngle = 145
        .Visible = True
    End With
    shp.Name = "btnDel" & rw
    shp.OnAction = "delRow"
End Sub
```

--The action of the shape:

```
Sub delRow()
Plan1.Unprotect ("password")
Dim shp As Object
Set shp = Plan1.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Dim rw As Long
rw = shp.TopLeftCell.Row
Dim doc As String
doc = Plan1.Cells(rw, 2).Value
Dim msgResult As VbMsgBoxResult
msgResult = MsgBox("Você deseja deletar o documento " + doc + "?", vbYesNo)
If msgResult = vbYes Then
    Plan1.Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Plan1.Protect ("password")
End Sub
```

**The problem is** that some times (I haven't found a pattern yet) the button from one row will delete another upper row. I can't find out why, can you see it?

Comment: I like your functionality of the macros.  Is it possible that you are having the shp object getting set by one macro then another calls it and it's a different range?  You are setting the rw by TopLeftCell, could you set each macro's code more definitively as to where it is being placed when you create it?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain a bit better what's going on. But still, I don't quite get what you're trying to say there, @PJRosenburg.

Comment: Let me ask this:  Are you using more than one of these at a time?

Comment: There are multiple shapes that use that function at one time in the sheet, but they do not go off at the same time.

Comment: But they all use the same method to define them?  Is it possible that you create Button 1, then later create Button2.  If you click button1, is it possible that it affects the range and rw of Button2?

Comment: Regardless, I would insert a breakpoint in your macro.  Then step through it and watch the Locals.  See when the value for rw is changing.  That should tell you what's going on.

Comment: Please don't send emails to site members. If people want to answer, they will. If they don't, leave them alone. Asking people per email to look at your question is spam, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see why this would happen. Everything looks alright with the code.

Once I also wanted to make very similar functionality and realized that using many dynamically created buttons is not the best option (at least not for me).

I have abandoned the idea of shapes and make similar functionality with `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. With some nice formating you can make the cells in the column looks like some Delete Buttons. The `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event (for cells) works like `OnClick` event (for buttons / `OnAction` for shapes).

Example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Column = 5 Then 'If the clicked cell is in the column 5
    Dim doc As String
    doc = Cells(Target.row, 2).Value
    Dim msgResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    msgResult = MsgBox("Voce^ deseja deletar o documento " + doc + "?", vbYesNo)
    If msgResult = vbYes Then
        Plan1.Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If

ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The `ErrorHandler` with Disabling events is important to prevent the `row.delete` event to trigger another `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.